# Runtime Exception while creating EJB Object

Tags: jboss, ejb-2.x, session-bean, runtimeexception

I have developed an application with Java 1.6, EJB-2.1. The application is deployed on JBossAS-5.1.0. The application has been running very smooth for long a time. But for last two days, I found following sort of Runtime Exception while creating EJB Local Object/Local Home:

**Log Snippet-1**:

```
2012-01-25 17:09:02,896 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkerThread#4[127.0.0.1:47153])
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2012-01-25 17:09:02,896 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkerThread#4[127.0.0.1:47153])
at
org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invokeHome(BaseLocalProxyF
actory.java:343)
2012-01-25 17:09:02,896 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkerThread#4[127.0.0.1:47153])
at
org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.LocalHomeProxy.invoke(LocalHomeProxy.java:133)
2012-01-25 17:09:02,896 ERROR [STDERR] (WorkerThread#4[127.0.0.1:47153])
at $Proxy257.create(Unknown Source)
```

**Log Snippet-2**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:457)
      at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatelessSessionProxy.invoke(StatelessSessionProxy.java:103)
      at $Proxy263.getDynamicLoopMessage_Generalized(Unknown Source)
```

**Log Snippet-3**:

```
2012-01-17 16:44:49,063 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor]  
   (WorkerThread#5[192.168.1.76:19743]) RuntimeException in method: public abstract     
com.elitecore.billingengine.utils.BEResultObject   

com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.billpreview.interfaces.IBillPreviewSessionLocal.doBasePriceCalcul    ation(com.elitecore.billingengine.utils.BEHashMap):
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at     
com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.billpreview.sessionfacade.BillPreviewSessionFacade.doBasePriceCal    culation(BillPreviewSessionFacade.java:357)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at                    
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Can anyone pls. suggest some pointers on the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from your logs, but I would surmise this is a null pointer in the constructor of an instance of `com.elitecore.billingengine.utils.BEResultObject`. Most of the rest of the logs snippets are just that exception being propagated by the jboss invocation layer.